# how to read multi separated hashmaps into JSONObject or to HashMap - java

Tags: java, android, json, gson

i hope you are fine.

i have a data String of HashMaps every one in line, i tried to read it using new JSONObject(data) but no success(the JSONObject get only one hashmap), and also using

```
HashMa<String, Object> hashMap = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, new TypeToken<HashMap<String, Object>>(){}.getType());
```

also not working i get error as if it is not valid Json String, so i thought there another way i still do not know. i hope you help me know it. at least guide me by telling me what i need.

the JSON DATA

```
{"resFullName":"close.png","resName":"close","resType":1}
{"resFullName":"save.png","resName":"save","resType":1}
{"resFullName":"exit.png","resName":"exit","resType":1}
{"resFullName":"add.png","resName":"add","resType":1}
{"resFullName":"html.png","resName":"html","resType":1}
{"resFullName":"python.png","resName":"python","resType":1}
{"resFullName":"txt.png","resName":"txt","resType":1}
{"resFullName":"file.png","resName":"file","resType":1}
{"resFullName":"delete_big.png","resName":"delete_big","resType":1}
```

Comment: What if spliting String per skip line and treat each line as JSON?

Comment: @RAZAFINARIVO Hanania i have think about that, but just im curios to know if there is a way i do not know it. and yes your idea surely will work

Comment: If you can switch to Jackson: https://cowtowncoder.medium.com/line-delimited-json-with-jackson-69c9e4cb6c00

Comment: In Gson, 1) use `JsonParser.parseReader` to read elements one-by-one (it can read even multielement JSON files); 2) collect each element to the `JsonObject` by extracting the key using `getAsJsonObject().get("resFullName")`. That's it. Don't use `Gson` instances and its `fromJson` unless it really needed (it does not seem to be nedeed for your case). + Aren't you confused with `JSONObject` from javax and `JsonObject` from Gson?

Comment: @fluffy ah thank you brother for you answer. no im not confused, i know they are different JsonObject and JSONObject

Comment: @Hasni, you can also use [`BufferedReader.readLine()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/BufferedReader#readLine()) to split the lines in an efficient way before passing them to Gson. `JsonParser` suggested above has the disadvantage that it is _lenient_ (though that is unfortunately not well documented); it accepts JSON which does not comply with the strict requirements specified by the JSON specification.